# Byte[] audio stream, how to decode/playback?

Tags: android, c, sockets, audio, stream

Currently I have a client/server application in which the server communicates to the client an audio stream in the form of a byte array.

The server in this case is an Android device and the client is a Raspberry Pi. The client establishes a Bluetooth connection and both are able to send/receive packets without issue, however I am having trouble with finding the appropriate library to read from the stream buffer on client to play an audio file from the server in real time.

In this case the client application is written in C and I am unsure of how to interpret the client buffer.

Comment: Well, what does the server send?

Comment: At the moment I am splitting the audio file into a byte array which is sent and rebuilt on the client and I imagine should be redirected to a decoder while it is being received.

Comment: So you're just sending the whole file, with no decoding or anything? Then what you're looking for is a way to play an audio file from an InputStream (so it actually doesn't have to be a file) - do I have that right?

Comment: Yep, thats right. Does the stream need to be of audio frames to be decided properly or can I feed the Inputstream to a decoder.